# Pass input to a C program and get output using php

Tags: php, c, variables, input

I am working on a project and I wrote two C programs that convert date and time into minutes and then back. What I want to do is pass a php variable into a C program and then have the C program return the result to a variable in php.

I realize that you can use popen or exec commands but I am unsure how to use these commands.

How would I structure the php code? 
What input and output commands would I have to use in the C program? If you guys could give me a few examples that would  be great. I learn better from examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your goal isn't just to convert time, right? You can do that in native PHP better and faster.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php Php date() function reference.

Comment: No, what I am trying to do is to take the date and time and covert it into minutes since 00:00 Jan 1st of 2012 so I can store the number of minutes into a database. Then I want to take those minutes and convert them back into date and time.

Comment: @maknelly: `$your_time = strtotime($your_date_string) - strtotime('2012-01-01 00:00:00');`. no need for C at all.

Comment: Curious, why don't you just implement it in PHP?

Comment: There's no legitimate reason to do this using anything other than php as far as I can see.

Comment: Can you just call the C programs over the command line?  Maybe just try shell_exec or exec before moving to popen.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys! I feel really dumb now. I am new to php and much more accomplished with C. I felt more comfortable coding in C. I will try doing php thank you!

Comment: This would've been such an interesting question for PHP/C communication, but if it's all just for date calculations... Meh. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cmd = "/path/to/prog " . escapeshellarg($something);
$c_output = shell_exec($cmd);
```